# jquery выезжающий блок, изначально открыт. Как скрыть по умолчанию?

Tags: jquery, mootools

Здравствуйте друзья, и снова прошу вашей помощи у знающий людей. Буду очень признателен и благодарен.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Lets make the top panel toggle based on the click of the show/hide link
  $("#sub-panel").click(function() {
    // Toggle the bar up
    $("#top-panel").slideToggle();
    // Settings
    var el = $("#shText");
    // Lets us know whats inside the element
    var state = $("#shText").html();
    // Change the state
    state = (state == 'Hide' ? '<span id="shText">Открыть</span>' : '<span id="shText">Закрыть</span>');
    // Finally change whats insdide the element ID
    el.replaceWith(state);
  }); // end sub panel click function
}); // end on DOM
```

```css
body {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #555555;
}
a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #0066CC;
}
#top-panel {
  background: #e8f3c6;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #a6c34e;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-align: right;
}
#sub-panel {
  text-align: center;
}
#sub-panel a {
  width: 150px;
  float: right;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: url(img/sub-left.png) bottom left no-repeat #a6c34e;
}
#sub-panel a span {
  padding: 6px;
  background: url(img/sub-right.png) right bottom no-repeat;
  display: block;
}
strong {
  color: #000000;
}
.face {
  border: solid 2px #a6c34e;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: right;
}
:focus {
  outline: 0
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<div id="top-panel">

  Что нам стоит, дом построить.


</div>
<div id="sub-panel"><a href="#" id="toggle"><span id="shText">Hide</span></a>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
```

По умолчанию блок открыт сразу. Как сделать чтобы он был скрыт?

Answer (score 2):

В css:

```
 display:none;
```

А после уже оперировать над параметром `display`.